# How to create a 3D layer explosion/expansion in Photoshop?

Tags: photoshop-effects, style-identification, isometric

I need to depict a bunch of layers of an image similar to this:

[image: Layer explosion]

What is this style called? Is there any photoshop plugins that can automatically create this kind of view?

Comment: You don't need a plugin just select the layers tarsnform into isometric view and offset

Comment: How do I do that? This is basically what I understood: http://i0.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/original/000/572/078/d6d.jpg

Comment: See my answer. Its pretty self contained explanation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ok, here is how you do this. Prepare your image layers and all. Im going to be using a very simple image with colored squares.

[image: simple setup]

**Image 1:** Original setup with simple shapes, this would work with any layered source however.

Select ALL your layers you intend to stack up, into isometric or perspective. I will be transforming to isometric [[1](http://design.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-advanced-isometric-illustrations-using-the-ssr-method--vector-1058)].

1. Scale down horizontally 86,60254037% using **Edit → Transform → Scale**
2. Skew down horizontally 30 (or -30) degrees using  **Edit → Transform → Skew**
3. Rotate -30 (or 30 if you skewed -30) degrees using  **Edit → Transform → Rotate**
4. (Optional) scale to fit

[image: Isometric transform of layers]

**Image 2:** Layers after isometric transform

Then shift layers upwards with move tool (holding shift down and by hitting <kbd>↑</kbd> for precise control. **Tip** if you want a shadow or see where the layers started from duplicate them and hide the original guides are then easier to produce.

[image: Final image with offset]

**Image 3:** Result with outlines of layer positions on layer below.

Decorate to your hears content. Done. Ideas for improvement:

- turn layers into smart objects befre transformation

#### References:

1. Walker C., 2009. [*How to Create Advanced Isometric Illustrations Using the SSR Method*](http://design.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-advanced-isometric-illustrations-using-the-ssr-method--vector-1058), Tutsplus, referenced 08/07/2014

Comment: Ace! Any good ideas about how to add the edges to give the layers 'thickness'?

Comment: @Vincent Duplicate many layers in pixel increments on top of eachother?

Comment: clunky, but easy.

Comment: @Vincent Too bad you can not make colored image brushes in photoshop then youd just stroke the image upward. Or you can build sides like explained in the reference.

Comment: @joojaa, is there a video of this? Your steps are not entirely complete, for a novice user. You presume some steps between those steps. It would be nice to see if I have two images in two layers, what precisely to do thereafter, in which menu, changing what precise value, where. Thank you.

Comment: @PKHunter what part are you stuck with?

Answer (score 0):

I just came across a question that was marked as a duplicate of this one (which is mostly is) but it also included this image:

[image]

I just wanted to add that I found a useful web tool for quickly creating these angled images in nicely rendered device frames, it's called ["MockUPhone"](http://mockuphone.com/).There's a good range of iOS and Android device frames available so I've found it to be a good way to create promo images for my app projects.

You need to give them an email address to send the files to, which also signs you up to a newsletter, but they seem pretty good. I have not been hassled with emails from them and I've been using the site a couple of months now.

Hope that's a helpful addition for anyone wanting to create this popular style of promo image.

Comment: Looks pretty useful thanks! But those are a different style of renders. The type of render from the question gives a sense of layers, where as the website you showed are product mockups.