# What is the precise transform for a circle onto an isometric grid?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, grids, transform

What are the precise parameters of the ellipse that results when a circle of diameter 1 is projected from an orthonormal grid onto an isometric grid?

Working on isometric transformation of my TTRPG art assets into isometric space. Thank you!

Comment: Use scale skew and rotate. Google for ssr method, and make sure you put correct values in as googles number one hit has a typo

Comment: The procrdure is outlined on https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/37016/how-to-create-a-3d-layer-explosion-expansion-in-photoshop/37037#37037

Comment: Also related: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/133830

Comment: If you have access to Inkscape (which is free), it has a  Perspective Distort Live Path Effect which can be used to do this visually without any maths. You can snap the distort handles to an isometric grid. [see example](https://imgur.com/zYK16iX)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you already know this:

[image]

There's as faint blue the ordinary isometric grid (see **NOTE1**) which actually contains the isometric images of tiled 1 unit x 1 unit x 1 unit cubes. When measured in the image above, the lengths of the green and red lines are not 1 in the original XY-plane units, they are the isometric projections of 1 unit long sides of a square.

The black ellipse presents a XY-plane circle. It's the one which is easy to draw into the grid, because it snaps. Unfortunately its diameter is 1,41 units, exactly 1 unit multiplied by sqrt(2) where the sqrt means square root.

**You wanted** an ellipse which presents a XY-plane circle which has diameter = 1 unit. Unfortunately that ellipse will not snap to the grid. Making the grid denser does not help (see **NOTE2**), because sqrt(2) is an irrational number. One cannot form it by adding together fractions of 1 unit. It can only be approximated.

A practical way to construct the isometric image of an 1 unit diameter XY-plane circle in isometric grid is to draw the shown black ellipse and scale it to 1/sqrt(2) = 70,7% It's not exact, but probably accurate enough for art purposes. The horizontally oriented blue ellipse in the next image is the isometric projection of 1 unit diameter XY plane circle:

[image]

The blue ellipse still has width = 1 unit in the original XY-plane units because just that direction length is not distorted in isometric projection. The height of the ellipse is 1 original XY plane unit divided by sqrt(3).

**NOTE1:** It's a  bunch of equally spaced vertical lines and 2 copies of that bunch. Copy 1 is rotated counterclockwise 60 degrees. Copy 2 is copied 60 degrees clockwise. As well it can seen as a plane filled with equal equilateral triangles.

**NOTE2**: That's not an exact truth. If one uses Inkscape he has snapping modes "Snap to nodes", "Snap to path crossings" and"Snap to grids" available at the same time. If one has double density isometric grid he can make the 1 unit diameter circle without numerical scaling to 70,7%. An example:

The easy to draw circle is in the double density grid. The diameter of the circle is sqrt(2) in original XY-plane units. The green line is drawn either along the X- or Y-direction gridline over the ellipse curve:

[image]

The next step is to convert the ellipse to path, bring it to front and place to the ellipse a new node at the crossing of the green line:

[image]

Now the ellipse can be scaled by dragging it from the bounding box corner and holding at the same time Ctrl and Shift. This keeps the centerpoint and proportions intact. The new node snaps to the grid:

[image]

The tangent lines in the double density grid are so good references that in Illustrator one may well succeed by eyeballing to scale the easy to draw ellipse to the right 1 unit size so accurately that the biggest zoom-in cannot show any error. Only hold Alt+Shift as you drag the corner. That keeps the proportions and the center intact.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do it is by using the 3d feature in Illustrator. It gives you a free transform as also some predefined isometric shapes. This is a non-destructive way to achieve it in Illustrator.

Menu: Effects > 3d > rotate...

In this example, I used the predefined isometric top position.
You can play with the values to match your grid.

[image]

Comment: Maybe useful: Isometric view preset in llustrator's 3D effects uses coarse viewing angles. The result will not fit into isometric grid as accurately as polygon shapes in Illustrator generally are drawn. For ex a 100 mm wide object can easily have 0,2 mm error which is not fixable by scaling, the corner nodes must be moved separately to make it fit. That's not much but someone can see that 0,2 mm gap or overlap annoying. There's no problem if one doesn't try to mix items drawn with a grid and items transformed with 3D effects.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the SSR (Scale Skew Rotate) method. Good thing about this is that you can record the thing into a action and use it over and over again on any shape. Once you understand the underpinnings its also easier to use then the 3d rotate effect for accurately matching other transforms.

**The SSR method and its underpinning**

Essentially for isometric drawing all you need to do is rotate the axes of your coordinate system, individually. Eps, pdf and svg all alow you to do this.

[image]

Unfortunately illustrator does not have a gui for this. So you need to do it in 3 steps.

Since the only tools illustrator has for manipulating individual axes is scale and shear. We need to use those. These can only manipulate individual axes when they are orthogonal though. But thats not a problem.

So what we do is we scale down one axis and then shear. This accomplishes same as rotate, since shearing is just rotation without keeping scale. What we want is a 120 degree separation for the axes.

- So we scale down by cos(30) which is 86.60254%
- And shear by 30 degrees.

We then rotate to get the correct orientation.

- Rotate by -30 degrees. To get bottom plane.

Essentially thats why it is called the Scale Skew Rotate (SSR) method.

PS: Illustrator can not make a circle. Illustrators circle is always down by bézier curves, so it is a approximation at best. For similar reasons the iso circle is also only an approximation. But it is quite close approximation. although not on scientific scale.

Comment: How do you create the animation?

Comment: I wrote a animation code in Mathematica @IvanZ